# How to write rewrite rule in htaccess for allowing access to another folder in project?

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I've this project structure
[image]

I save images in folder data/images.
I want to allow access to this folder by direct link.
My .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

How to do it ?

Comment: Is your web root the folder "*public*"? In this case you don't have access because it's higher in the hierarchy. You have to move the image folder into the public folder if its content should be accessible through *HTTP*. Then you can use a rule like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/images/"` to allow access.

Comment: If `data/images` is below your document root, your rules are already sufficient.

Comment: Yes, web root is the folder public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted at in the comments, you can't do this simply by modifying the htaccess file because your images folder is above the document root. You need to either move the `data/images` folder to `public/images`, or create a symlink from `public/images` to `data/images`. Then your images should work without any htaccess changes.